# Gamepad not properly detected

Tags: 18.04, gamepad

I'm having some issues with a wireless gamepad controller in Ubuntu 18.04. It was working fine until recently. jstest and evtest both seem to detect input from it but the button mappings are incorrect and games/emulators don't seem to recognize it.

lsusb returns this:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 17e9:436e DisplayLink 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0b0e:0301 GN Netcom 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0461:4d22 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 17e9:436e DisplayLink 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 048d:8297 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 11c1:9101  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I noticed there's a device with no descriptor/name (11c1:9101), which turns out to be the gamepad.

Details of the device from running 'lsusb -d 11c1:9101 -v':

```
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 11c1:9101  
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x11c1
  idProduct          0x9101
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1  
  iProduct                2 ESM-9013
  iSerial                 0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           41
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     137
         Report Descriptors:
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               4
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               4
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

It seems like the gamepad is being identified as a HID device which is probably part of the issue, not sure how to resolve it though. Results of running 'dmesg | grep hid' to confirm this:

```
[    4.860713] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    4.873302] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    4.873302] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    4.874614] hid-generic 0003:048D:8297.0001: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Device [ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8595)] on usb-0000:01:00.0-8/input0
[    4.874749] hid-generic 0003:11C1:9101.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Gamepad [   ESM-9013] on usb-0000:01:00.0-10/input0
[    5.805426] hid-generic 0003:0461:4D22.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:01:00.0-9.2.1/input0
[    6.360241] hid-generic 0003:413C:2107.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Dell Dell USB Entry Keyboard] on usb-0000:01:00.0-9.2.2/input0
[   14.272182] jabra 0003:0B0E:0301.0005: input,hiddev1,hidraw4: USB HID v1.00 Device [GN Netcom A/S Jabra EVOLVE 20] on usb-0000:01:00.0-9.2.3/input3
[ 1094.275956] hid-generic 0003:057E:2009.0006: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Joystick [  PC USB CONTROLLER 1.06] on usb-0000:01:00.0-10/input0
[ 1095.247965] hid-generic 0003:11C1:9101.0007: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Gamepad [   ESM-9013] on usb-0000:01:00.0-10/input0
```

Looks like there are three different entries for the gamepad, I only have one connected.

It may also be some sort of conflict with steamos-xpad-dkms, I remember using it with a Steam game and afterwards it stopped being detected by games the next time I tried using it.

**UPDATE 06-01-2020**

Here is some unusual activity I noticed in the syslog:

```
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 kernel: [26378.903526] hid-generic 0003:057E:2009.0025: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Joystick [  PC USB CONTROLLER 1.06] on usb-0000:01:00.0-10/input0
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 systemd-udevd[1211]: Process '/usr/bin/jscal-restore /dev/input/js0' failed with exit code 1.
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2430]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device   PC USB CONTROLLER 1.06 (/dev/input/js0)
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2430]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2430]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11095]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device   PC USB CONTROLLER 1.06 (/dev/input/js0)
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11095]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11095]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11095]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device   PC USB CONTROLLER 1.06 (/dev/input/event16)
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11095]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11095]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2430]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device   PC USB CONTROLLER 1.06 (/dev/input/event16)
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2430]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2430]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 upowerd[2639]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/0003:057E:2009.0025
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 upowerd[2639]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 upowerd[2639]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-10
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 kernel: [26379.152145] usb 1-10: USB disconnect, device number 38
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 upowerd[2639]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/0003:057E:2009.0025
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 upowerd[2639]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0
Jun  1 00:50:04 viru-b450 upowerd[2639]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-10
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 kernel: [26379.503364] usb 1-10: new full-speed USB device number 39 using xhci_hcd
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 kernel: [26379.835592] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=11c1, idProduct=9101, bcdDevice= 1.00
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 kernel: [26379.835595] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 kernel: [26379.835596] usb 1-10: Product: ESM-9013
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 kernel: [26379.835597] usb 1-10: Manufacturer:  
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 kernel: [26379.861838] input:    ESM-9013 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/0003:11C1:9101.0026/input/input48
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 39: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-10"
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 39 was not an MTP device
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 kernel: [26379.919868] hid-generic 0003:11C1:9101.0026: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Gamepad [   ESM-9013] on usb-0000:01:00.0-10/input0
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 systemd-udevd[1229]: Process '/usr/bin/jscal-restore /dev/input/js0' failed with exit code 1.
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2430]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device    ESM-9013 (/dev/input/js0)
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2430]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2430]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11095]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device    ESM-9013 (/dev/input/js0)
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11095]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11095]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2430]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device    ESM-9013 (/dev/input/event16)
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2430]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2430]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 upowerd[2639]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/0003:11C1:9101.0026
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 upowerd[2639]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 upowerd[2639]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-10
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11095]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device    ESM-9013 (/dev/input/event16)
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11095]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Jun  1 00:50:05 viru-b450 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11095]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

evtest results:

```
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Power Button
/dev/input/event1:  Power Button
/dev/input/event2:  USB Optical Mouse
/dev/input/event3:  Dell Dell USB Entry Keyboard
/dev/input/event4:  HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/dev/input/event5:  HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/dev/input/event6:  HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/dev/input/event7:  HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=9
/dev/input/event8:  HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=10
/dev/input/event9:  HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=11
/dev/input/event10: HD-Audio Generic Front Mic
/dev/input/event11: HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic
/dev/input/event12: HD-Audio Generic Line
/dev/input/event13: HD-Audio Generic Line Out
/dev/input/event14: HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone
/dev/input/event15: GN Netcom A/S Jabra EVOLVE 20
/dev/input/event16:    ESM-9013
Select the device event number [0-16]: 16
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x11c1 product 0x9101 version 0x111
Input device name: "   ESM-9013"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 304 (BTN_SOUTH)
    Event code 305 (BTN_EAST)
    Event code 306 (BTN_C)
    Event code 307 (BTN_NORTH)
    Event code 308 (BTN_WEST)
    Event code 309 (BTN_Z)
    Event code 310 (BTN_TL)
    Event code 311 (BTN_TR)
    Event code 312 (BTN_TL2)
    Event code 313 (BTN_TR2)
    Event code 314 (BTN_SELECT)
    Event code 315 (BTN_START)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value    128
      Min        0
      Max      255
      Flat      15
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value    128
      Min        0
      Max      255
      Flat      15
    Event code 2 (ABS_Z)
      Value    128
      Min        0
      Max      255
      Flat      15
    Event code 5 (ABS_RZ)
      Value    128
      Min        0
      Max      255
      Flat      15
    Event code 16 (ABS_HAT0X)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
    Event code 17 (ABS_HAT0Y)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1591054847.916049, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 76
Event: time 1591054847.916049, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1591054847.924049, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 0
Event: time 1591054847.924049, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1591054847.976047, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 106
Event: time 1591054847.976047, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1591054847.984044, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 66
Event: time 1591054847.984044, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1591054847.992050, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 17
Event: time 1591054847.992050, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1591054848.000040, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 6
Event: time 1591054848.000040, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 0
```

udevadm info:

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-9/1-9.4/1-9.4:1.0/0003:11C1:9101.0006/input/input17/event16
N: input/event16
S: input/by-id/usb-_ESM-9013-event-joystick
S: input/by-path/pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:9.4:1.0-event-joystick
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:9.4:1.0-event-joystick /dev/input/by-id/usb-_ESM-9013-event-joystick
E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/event16
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-9/1-9.4/1-9.4:1.0/0003:11C1:9101.0006/input/input17/event16
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=input-pci-0000_01_00_0-usb-0_9_4_1_0
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK=1
E: ID_MODEL=ESM-9013
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=ESM-9013
E: ID_MODEL_ID=9101
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:9.4:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_01_00_0-usb-0_9_4_1_0
E: ID_REVISION=0100
E: ID_SERIAL=_ESM-9013
E: ID_TYPE=hid
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030000:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=\x20\x20
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=11c1
E: LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=3/11c1/9101:usb-0000:01:00.0-9
E: MAJOR=13
E: MINOR=80
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: TAGS=:uaccess:seat:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=75198405
```

The Dolphin emulator properly recognizes it at evdev/0/ but other emulators such as VBA-M and Snes9x fail to recognize it correctly despite previously working fine.

Comment: Have you tried disabling/removing the steam gamepad compatibility layer?

Comment: Yes. I think I have managed to pin it down to the device being loaded with usbhid instead of xpad, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: are you sure that the `xpad` driver ever managed your controller? I couldn't find your specific device mentioned in the driver's list of supported devices. Also, the output of `evtest` looks like `hid-generic` detects it just fine. Is there a `/dev/input/js*` device created for the gamepad? IIRC older emulators only support joystick devices.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the same brand controller (ESM-9101) was being detected as "switch pro controller" for some reason and it messed up the inputs as well. Recently discovered that you can blacklist this "input device type" in the modprobe and this allowed the controlled to finally be detected as generic xbox controller.

Original place where I found the solution and the [code](https://steamcommunity.com/app/353380/discussions/0/2567564516570662457/?l=norwegian#c3490879077209818755):

> ```
> echo  'install hid_nintendo /bin/true' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
> ```
>
> or/and
>
> ```
> echo 'blacklist hid_nintendo' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/no-nintendo.conf
> ```