# Gamepad not working properly "DragonRise"

Tags: usb, gamepad

I am using ubuntu 20.04

When I plug a gamepad recognized as DragonRise Inc

with sdl-jstest (or jstest-gtk) when I move the :

left stick vertical : axe 1 move

left stick horizontal : axe0 and axe2 move together

right stick vertical : axe 2 move and bouton0 is set to 1

right stick horizontal: bouton1 is set to 1 when move to left ; bouton3 is set to 1 when move to right

I have read post talking about calibration problem but I think it is more than the driver load for the gamepad is not the good one

any idee to solve the problem ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you add the vendor/product ID of the DragonRise gamepad? Also, please add a link to a product page where the gamepad can be purchased.

Comment: lsusb gives :Bus 001 Device 015: ID 0079:0006 DragonRise Inc. PC TWIN SHOCK Gamepad

Comment: DragonRise hardware is generic, many gaming input devices use the 0079:0006 IDs but need different button/axis mappings which makes it difficult (or impossible) to support them out of the box. You'll probably need to configure your own mappings using a tool like the SDL2 Gamepad Tool. https://generalarcade.com/gamepadtool/

Comment: my problem is more complicate as only mapping... when I move a stick 2 axes are moving togeter... I have to "tell" to the kernel to use another driver...

Comment: hi @Ewok2 , maybe you could have a look at my question , as I am just a step behind you : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245625/gamepad-not-properly-detected